# How do I call a function upon clicking a vgui button

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

(I am fairly new to Lua so please excuse any mistakes I have made trying to explain this) I am trying to make a quest system so that a player can click on a quest when they open an entity and choose to start it. I can't seem to figure out how I can make it so that my "function npcquestkill()" only starts when a player clicks the quest button to start it. The quest button is "local Button = vgui.Create("DButton", Frame)". What could be a way I could go about doing this.

```
net.Receive("OBJ_OPEN", function()
        local Frame = vgui.Create("DFrame")
        Frame:SetPos( 700, 400 ) 
        Frame:SetSize( 500, 350 ) 
        Frame:SetTitle( "Objectives" ) 
        Frame:SetVisible( true ) 
        Frame:SetDraggable( false ) 
        Frame:ShowCloseButton( true ) 
        Frame:MakePopup()
        Frame.Paint = function( self, w, h ) 
            draw.RoundedBox( 0, 0, 0, w, h, Color( 231, 76, 60, 150 ) ) 
        end

        local Button = vgui.Create("DButton", Frame)
        Button:SetText( "Kill 10 Covenant in One Session" )
        Button:SetTextColor( Color(255,255,255) )
        Button:SetPos( 5, 30 )
        Button:SetSize( 490, 50 )
        Button.Paint = function( self, w, h )
            draw.RoundedBox( 0, 0, 0, w, h, Color( 41, 128, 185, 250 ) ) -- Draw a blue button
        end

        Button.DoClick = function()
            Button:SetText( "Kill 10 Covenant in One Session: In Progress")
            vbutton = 2
        end

        if (vbutton == 2) then
            Button:SetText( "Kill 10 Covenant in One Session: In Progress")
        elseif (vbutton == 1) then
            Button:SetText( "Kill 10 Covenant in One Session" )
        end
end)

function npcquestkill()
    npckills = npckills + 1
    print(npckills)
end

function rewards(ply)
    if(npckills == 50)then
        ply:AddMoney(1000)
        vbutton = 1
    end
end
hook.Add("OnNPCKilled","npcquestkill", npcquestkill)
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code? you implement DoClick so you seem to know hot to handle button clicks already. what is the expected/observed behaviour, what is your actual question?
have you tried calling npcquestkill in DoClick?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DButton documentation](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/DButton) you have to implement the function

```
Button.DoClick
```

As you already did.

This function will be called when the button is left-clicked (press and release)

### official example

> ```
> local frame = vgui.Create( "DFrame" )
> frame:SetSize( 300, 250 )
> frame:Center()
> frame:MakePopup()
>
> local DermaButton = vgui.Create( "DButton", frame ) // Create the button and parent it to the frame
> DermaButton:SetText( "Say hi" )                   // Set the text on the button
> DermaButton:SetPos( 25, 50 )                  // Set the position on the frame
> DermaButton:SetSize( 250, 30 )                    // Set the size
> DermaButton.DoClick = function()              // A custom function run when clicked ( note the . instead of : )
>   RunConsoleCommand( "say", "Hi" )            // Run the console command "say hi" when you click it ( command, args )
> end
> ```

Please note that you have to replace `//` with `--`

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to figure out how I can make it so that my "function npcquestkill()" only starts when a player clicks the quest button to start it.

Currently that function is hooked to the event "OnNPCKilled" which you hook into the moment the script is ran:

```
hook.Add("OnNPCKilled","npcquestkill", npcquestkill)
```

This means the function npcquestkill is executed every single time an npc is killed.

You can make it so the hook gets added when the button is pressed instead, or use a condition so your count will only increment after the button has been pressed.

With all that said, if this is for multiplayer you should probabably instead create a class which creates player objects that each individually maintain their own count. Unless of course its a server wide event with only a single count mattering.